# Return Earliest Date from a range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have an excel spreadsheet where I want to pull the earliest date in the column based on the criteria in a different column (for a given tech) into a different sheet. Rows on sheet1 contain store locations with a tech name and a date for that store. Rows on sheet2 contain the tech name and need start and end dates.

### *Sheet 1*

```
Instll Date  Tech Name
 01/27/14     tech 02
 01/27/14     tech 01
 01/28/14     tech 01
 01/28/14     tech 02
 01/29/14     tech 01
 01/29/14     tech 02
 01/30/14     tech 02
 01/30/14     tech 01
 01/31/14     tech 01
 01/31/14     tech 02
```

### *Sheet 2*

```
Tech Name   Start Date  End Date
 tech 01     
 tech 02
```

I would like to pull the earliest date from sheet1 on columnB for Tech01 and place it in columnB on Sheet 2 in the row for Tech01 under either Start Date or End Date. The same goes for Tech02, Tech03, etc. I was trying to use MAX and MIN, but could only return a date of 1/00/00.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Are the `Instll Date` guaranteed to be in order from older date to newer date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula for the start date:

```
=MIN(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100=A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100))
```

Entered as an array formula; i.e. using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

And this one (similar to the above) for the end date:

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100=A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100))
```

Assuming:

- `Sheet1!B2:B100` contains the tech names.
- `Sheet1!A2:A100` contains the Instll dates.
- `Sheet2!A2` contains the first tech name.

---

If the dates are guaranteed to be sorted, you can use this formula for the start date instead (which should be a little faster):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$11,0))
```